# Resource to see mining distribution

Tags: hashrate, mining-pools

I always check the health of a cryptocurrency by looking at its hash rate distribution.

Where can I see that information for Monero?

Answer (score 8):

https://monerohash.com/#network is a pretty good visualisation of the state of Monero mining. It also has some basic stats on nodes, and the blocks the monerohash pool has found.

Comment: Note that the blocks found are only from the pool MoneroHash itself. MoneroHash indeed provides a visualization of how the hasing power is distributed and how the nodes are distributed around the world. The node distribution can be found [here](https://monerohash.com/nodes-distribution.html).

Comment: http://minexmr.com/pools.html - shows the distribution of smaller pools as well

Answer (score 1):

[preview.moneropools.com](http://preview.moneropools.com/#/pie) has a pie chart showing the hashrate distribution of almost every public pool, including the unknown hashrate estimated from the network difficulty.